# In Azure Workbooks Bar chart x-axis labels are half-displayed or not displayed

Tags: azure, axis-labels, azure-monitor-workbooks

We are working on creating a custom connector to ingest the data in Azure Sentinel. We are now working on workbooks. But in workbooks, in the graphs, we are facing problem, that x-axis labels are getting half-displayed or are not getting displayed.

When we are using Bar chart as the query visualization, then the x-axis labels are getting overlapped, as shown below.
[image]

And when we are using Bar Chart(Categorical) as the visualization, then few x-axis labels are half-displayed, while few are now getting displayed, like in the below image just the first label is displayed

[image]

Can someone help me, how to show all the x-axis labels completely visible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a lot of this is not directly fixable by the workbooks team.  We depend on the Azure Portal's charting controls, and some things like the overlapping labels are things we've asked them to address.  The categorical only showing *one* of the labels seems like a new bug, i've added a bug for that (10739336 for my reference).  But even if all the labels were visible, we only have a fixed amount of space for the labels (otherwise a single long label could use up the whole chart area)

Another option is to instead us a grid, and set the column renderer for your value column to bar, and then set other various options there for color/scale (in this case, i picked 32-color categorical for color, and explicitly set the minimum value to 0, and marked it as counts (for large values, this would turn 1234 into 1.23k)

[image: bars in grid]

[image: column settings]

there are some other nice things about using grids for things like this:

1. the values are all there,
2. the text is all there,
3. the user can sort in whatever directions they want
4. you can turn on grid filtering as well, so a user can type to filter
5. by default, charts take the first 10, then merge all the rest into "other", the grid would show all the values from the start